# Passing an object with values from View to ActionResult using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

### I want to send an object from view to controller, ajax hits the action result but data is not being delivered to action result

View:

```
 function submit()
{
    var obj = {};
    obj.PD = getResult('pd');
    obj.MD = getResult('md');
    obj.C = getResult('c');
    obj.ME = getResult('me');
    obj.EE = getResult('ee');
    obj.SED = getResult('sed');
    obj.RT = getResult('rt');
    obj.SEA = getResult('sea');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Assessment/AssessNow',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: '{obj' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (res) {

        },
        error: function (msg) {
        }
    });
    //alert(getResult('pd'));
}
```

Model:

```
 public class QAViewModel
    {
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string EE { get; set; }
        public string MD { get; set; }
        public string ME { get; set; }
        public string PD { get; set; }
        public string RT { get; set; }
        public string SEA { get; set; }
        public string SED { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:
[image]

Comment: I suppose the error is in the json structure, try checking your request body in chrome develpoer tools-> network and post it here

Comment: The view 'AssessNow' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Assessment/AssessNow.aspx
~/Views/Assessment/AssessNow.ascx
~/Views/Shared/AssessNow.aspx
~/Views/Shared/AssessNow.ascx
~/Views/Assessment/AssessNow.cshtml
~/Views/Assessment/AssessNow.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/AssessNow.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/AssessNow.vbhtml

Comment: This is the response body, you should check the request body under the tab network -> Headers -> Request header and Query string parameters

Comment: didn't get you dear @laconis

Comment: Its just  data: obj` (or `data: stringify({ obj: obj }` with `contentType: 'application/json'`). But you need to remove `dataType: 'json',` since you method returns a view (or change it to `dataType: 'html'`). Alternatively have you method return a `JsonResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing as a good point was raised:

In the post you can just pass the full object like so:

```
 function submit()
{
    var obj = {};
    obj.PD = getResult('pd');
    obj.MD = getResult('md');
    obj.C = getResult('c');
    obj.ME = getResult('me');
    obj.EE = getResult('ee');
    obj.SED = getResult('sed');
    obj.RT = getResult('rt');
    obj.SEA = getResult('sea');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Assessment/AssessNow',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: obj,
        success: function (res) {

        },
        error: function (msg) {
        }
    });
    //alert(getResult('pd'));
}
```

If you want to stick with json then modify your ajax call accordingly (you error was in the way you were building the data property:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Assessment/AssessNow',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify({obj: obj}),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (res) {

                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                    }
                });
```

Also, depending on what you are doing with the result you may need to flip your controller actions to return JsonResult (Ignore if you are doing something such as returning a partial view to load):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Whatever(QAViewModel obj)
    {
        return Json(whatever, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: its a js object my dear not a string i think

Comment: @Ralis you do bring up a valid point looking back on this though so post edit for the correct json submit modifications as well.